# What are secret hats?

Tags: support, winterbash, hats

I just earned a Flip Flop on programmers!

Does anyone know what that might be, and more generally what secret hats are?

Comment: Head over to [Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270789/winter-bash-2015-secret-hats) for more (mis)information.